# AWS App Runner Health Check Fails Despite Successful Local Testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, tcp, health-check, aws-app-runner

Title: "AWS App Runner Health Check Fails Despite Successful Local Testing"
Description:
I have encountered an issue with the AWS App Runner service. I have created a service in the AWS App Runner, and my code runs successfully locally on port 3000 using HTTP. However, when I deploy it to the App Runner service, the build fails during the health checkup section. I have also tried using TCP, but the error persists. I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue.
Thank you for your help.

technology used : i am using nuxt2 (SSR) node version is 16

error is:
Health check failed on protocol `HTTP`[Path: '/'], [Port: '3000']. Check your configured port number. For more information, see the application logs.
01-23-2024 12:42:41 PM [AppRunner] Deployment with ID : .....54be failed. Failure reason : Health check failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4QaI.png)

i try with diffrent different port like 3000 default(8080) and also 80 but the issue same
also change the protocal to HTTP to TCP but the issue is same.

i am expecting that health check is passed and my webiste is hosted.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also in the same situation